# IAM Authorisation for API Gateway Request (AWS / .NET C#)

Tags: c#, amazon-web-services

I'm building a web API to allow some of our systems to raise incidents in our incident management system. I am fronting an AWS API Gateway for this purpose. I want to ensure the API calls are authenticated and require a valid IAM user. I am comfortable with C# / .NET Core, and have read up on using signature v4 to sign the requests. What I can't work out and need help with, is whether the client has to actually sign the requests themselves in the JSON payload being passed to the API Gateway, or whether they can pass the IAM access and secret key only, and then I do the coding to sign the request? I'm concerned that the third party systems won't have the developer knowledge required to sign the requests. They could pass in the IAM user and secret key easily enough, but not sure if they can actually do the signing themselves.